# User.Identity.IsAuthenticated is always false Even though e.Authenticated = true

Tags: c#, asp.net, authentication, webforms, login-control

I have searched similar question but could not solve the problem.

html code

```
  <asp:Login ID="Login1" runat="server" Width="247px"       OnAuthenticate="Login1_Authenticate1">
                </asp:Login>
```

C# code

```
public partial class login : System.Web.UI.Page
{
private SqlConnection con = new     SqlConnection(WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString);

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}
protected void Login1_Authenticate1(object sender, AuthenticateEventArgs e)
{
    string userName = Login1.UserName;
    string password = Login1.Password;

    bool result = UserLogin(userName, password);
    if ((result))
    {
        e.Authenticated = true;
        FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(userName, true);
        Response.Redirect("http://localhost:57000/Default");
    }
    else
    {
        e.Authenticated = false;
    }
}
private bool UserLogin(string userName, string password)
{

    //' declare the command that will be used to execute the select statement 
    SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("SELECT Employee_Email FROM Employee_Detail WHERE Employee_Email = @UserName AND Password = @Password", con);

        // set the username and password parameters
        com.Parameters.Add("@UserName", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = userName;
        com.Parameters.Add("@Password", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = password;

        con.Open();
        //' execute the select statment 
        string result = Convert.ToString(com.ExecuteScalar());
        //' check the result 
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(result))
        {
            //invalid user/password , return flase 
            return false;
        }
        else
        {
            // valid login
            return true;
        }
    }
```

}
I am checking like this.

     `if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            Page.Title = "Home page for " + User.Identity.Name;
        }
        else
        {
            Page.Title = "Home page for guest user.";
        }`
Config File

`<authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms defaultUrl="~/Default.aspx" loginUrl="~/login.aspx" name="__Auth" slidingExpiration="true" timeout="2880"></forms>
    </authentication>`

The login works fine but when check User.Identity.IsAuthenticated in next      page it is always false. i have set authentication as form in config page.
Any help would be great.

Answer (score 1):

You also have to set the `FormsAuthenticationTicket`

```
FormsAuthenticationTicket ticket = new FormsAuthenticationTicket(2, userName, DateTime.Now, DateTime.Now.AddDays(30), true, String.Empty);
string encryptedTicket = FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(ticket);
HttpCookie authenticationCookie = new HttpCookie(FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName, encryptedTicket);
authenticationCookie.Expires = ticket.Expiration;
Response.Cookies.Add(authenticationCookie);

FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(userName, true);
```

And it's better to use `RedirectFromLoginPage` instead of `Response.Redirect`

```
FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage(userName, true);
```

> It looks like you are storing plain text passwords. Don't do that.

**UPDATE**

```
<sessionState mode="InProc" cookieless="false" timeout="1440" />
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms cookieless="UseCookies" timeout="43200" defaultUrl="~/Default.aspx" loginUrl="~/login.aspx" />
</authentication>
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. i added `FormsAuthenticationTicket` Still i am getting same result. I have edited the question to show how i am checking. Also how should i store password? should i encrypt it?

Comment: Always encrypt passwords, with a Salt. And have you added all the nessecary `authentication` items [to the Web.Config](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1d3t3c61(v=vs.100).aspx)?

Comment: I have added please check the question i have edited to show confg file. Also `FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage(userName, true);` is not working

Comment: Define `not working`? And i've added an example of the Web.Config

Comment: About not working I gave checked in the default page whether the user is authenticated or not(please check question), If user is authenticated then it will show users name. But it is showing Guest user always after successful login.The redirect is working fine thanks for Update.

Comment: Is `aspnet Identity` installed? See this [complete turorial](https://www.asp.net/identity/overview/getting-started/adding-aspnet-identity-to-an-empty-or-existing-web-forms-project).

Comment: Yes it is installed. Also `FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage(userName, true);` which you suggested is not working.